# How to use seaborn library with pydatatable?

Tags: python, py-datatable

I have started using pydatatable for one of my data analysis project, here i have faced few issues in making charts of pydatatable object using seaborn library.

does pydatatable support seaborn visualizations in current version of it 0.8?.

I have tried to visualise a column with a chart : histogram, boxplot etc.etc. as showed in the sample code below

```py
np.random.seed(1)
dt_test = dt.Frame(np.random.randn(1000))
sns.boxplot(x="CO",data=dt_test)
plt.show()
```

On running above code chunk it should display a boxplot of the provided column, but here it's giving an error as

AttributeError: 'Frame' object has no attribute 'get'

Could you please write to me here how to solve this and have you ever tried to use these two packages together?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `seaborn` library does not support interoperating with `datatable` yet. On its part, a datatable Frame makes itself convertible to a numpy array. Thus, any code that does `np.asarray(data)` will be able to work with a datatable Frame. For this reason you'll see that datatable can currently be used in some functions but not others: it all depends on how the internal code treats the incoming data.

For example your example can be rewritten as

```
sns.boxplot(x=dt_test[:, "C0"])
```

and it will now work.

More generally, you can easily convert a datatable `Frame` into one of the formats that an external library can understand:

```
frame.to_pandas()
frame.to_numpy()
frame.to_list()
frame.to_dict()
```